# How do you turn Three Finger Drag on?

Tags: macos, multi-touch

I'm trying to use the new "three finger drag" gesture in Lion and it's not working. There isn't a preference setting for it in TrackPad -> Point and Click either. Does anyone know how to turn it on?

Answer (score 1):

Some older Macs only support [two finger scrolling](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3448) on the trackpad, not three. Since you're not seeing a setting for three finger drag, I'd guess your hardware just doesn't support it.

Are you able to do other gestures that require more than two fingers? If not, it's probably a hardware limitation, and you could just get a [Magic Trackpad](http://www.apple.com/magictrackpad/).

Comment: I can use, and have preferences for, the other 3 finger swipe gestures (move between spaces, Mission Control, App Expose, ect). For some reason I can't use, nor have a preference for, the 3 finger drag gesture.

Comment: @Toph I'm not sure I can help, then. Perhaps you can take it in to an Apple Store and see if they can help.

Comment: I'm on an old MBP, with a physical button with the pad. On 10.9, it supports, e.g. "look up with three fingers" tap, but not drag. Dunno why, but it's not b/c it can't recognize those gestures.

Answer (score 1):

I've been trying to figure this out as well and found it on another site , so here you go:

System Preferences->Universal Access->Mouse and Trackpad->Trackpad Options-> then you have your choice of dragging with or without draglock :)

Hope this helps!

Source: http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20110630003322997

Comment: This is not three finger drag. That option is located in *System Preferences > Trackpad > Point & Click > Three finger drag* **only** on Macs with multi-touch capable trackpads.

Answer (score 0):

If you look under all your settings, you have the option to change to 2 or 3 finger swipe.

Comment: The three finger swipe to change spaces works great, but I'm unable to use the three finger tap to drag a window. The gesture is mentioned at the bottom of this page: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4721